# Java Json Data transfer

Tags: java, json, jsonp

I need to implement Java,JSON for Data Transfer. How do i generate JSON on the below vector objects and get the objects back from JSON?

```
    vc.add("Vector Object 1");
    vc.add("Vector Object 2");
    vc.add("Vector Object 3");
    vc.add("Vector Object 4");
    vc.add("Vector Object 5");
```

Thanks

Comment: best way to use google gson library simple and effective http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: depends on the environment you are using - e.g. if you are using Spring MVC

Answer (score 3):

Google's gson library is another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

you can use org.json.jar
or StringBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [tutorial](http://java.sg/parsing-a-json-string-into-an-object-with-gson-easily/) for GSON to get you started, parsing a JSON String into an object. Though your requirement is the reverse, still handy. :)